# Spring Boot Actuator endpoints with set server.context-path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

In spring boot app I set e.g. `server.context-path=/mymodule`. This is convenient because I don't need to repeat over and over again `/mymodule` prefix in `@RequestMapping`. 
Further I want to have actuator endpoints grouped together on URLs with common prefix so I set `management.context-path=/actuator`.
Now actuator endpoint are mapped to `/mymodule/actuator`.

From security perspective I want to have actuator endpoints mapped to `/actuator`. Simple config on reverse proxy `https://mydomain/api/mymodule -> http://oneofmyserver:port/mymodule` protects that end users would not be able to access actuator.

Is it possible to map actuator endpoints to `/actuator`?

Comment: Instead of `server.context-path` set the `server.servlet-path` instead.

Comment: Setting `server.servlet-path` causes that actuator endpoints are still mapped to `/mymodule/actuator`.

Answer (score 9):

Probably better solution from security perspective is to export actuator on totally different port. To do it just add such properties:

```
management.port=9080
```

You can also just change context-path of actuator endpoints by using

```
management.context-path=/actuator
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I've thought earlier about this solutions, only additional port is drawback. Only problem I have is that Spring Cloud `org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance` do not expose `management.port`, so e.g. [spring-boot-admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-server) is not able to construct valid management URL to my microservice.

Comment: @ŁukaszIdkowiak just submit this as issue to Spring

Comment: We already have issues for this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/425

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `management.endpoints.web.base-path` property to change the prefix for your management endpoint. [Reference from spring-boot document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path).

The following example remaps **/actuator/health** to **/healthcheck**;

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of you aren't able to use different ports and you have, for example, eureka in you environment, you can use the following:

1. Configure additional metadata, that you send to eureka. Simply by adding there some parameter with value of your context-path. [spring docs](https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_eureka_metadata_for_instances_and_clients)
2. [Configure Prometheus for using Eureka](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#eureka_sd_config).
   After that you will get an access to your custom meta-data
3. Finally you can use these new parameters in a [relabeling step](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config).